# Custom Activities missing from Toolbox after upgrade from VS 2010 to VS 2012

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a large solution with a number of projects in it.

I recently upgraded to VS 2012 and changed the Target Framework of all the projects to .NET Framework 4.5.

I now cannot see any of my Custom Activities in the Toolbox.

My Custom Activities are in the same Project as the Flowchart activity I am building so should show up automatically.

If I use Choose Items I can load the Custom Activities into a Toolbar folder by pointing at the .dll.  I don't want to do that because it ties me to the debug or release dll.

I've tried a few things from the web but not found a solution.

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your solution in its entirety to see if the toolbox gets populated with all your activities?

Comment: Yes, Tried that.  Made no difference

Comment: Try deleting the 'obj' folder that VS creates, then rebuild again. Sometimes VS' refactoring gets corrupted leading to strange issues. That was the case many times when I was working on WF 3.5 workflows. Also, do you have a custom activity design project for your activities?

Comment: Forgot to mention that after deleting the 'obj' folder, you'll need to close/reopen VS. Hope that helps.

Comment: Deleting the obj folders didn't help with the toolbox problem.  I have been deleting the obj folders because they are causing other problems when compiling solutions containing resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed my code to Microsoft who tell me that this is a bug in VS 2012 and that it is solved in VS 2013

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the custom activities project target platform is AnyCPU. If it is set to x64, VS will not be able to load it as VS is still x86.